# Magento 1.8 redirect product child to parent product

Tags: magento

In magento 1.8.1, how can you redirect the child products to an associated parent bundled product?

It seems options I have found for past versions are not working.

For example, clicking on child product a while doing a search will take you to the parent item showing all of the options available.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple extension yesterday that does exactly this in 1.8. Set up an observer for the event `controller_action_predispatch`

My observer file looks like this

```
class CommerceExtensions_GroupedProductRedirect_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{  
  public function redirectProductView($observer)
  { 
    $id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    if($product->getTypeId() == 'simple' && $product->getVisibility() == 1){
      $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId()); 
      if(!empty($parentIds)){
        $parentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentIds[0]);
        Mage::app()
          ->getResponse()
          ->setRedirect($parentProduct->getProductUrl(), 301)
          ->sendResponse();
      }
    }           
  }
}
```

This is what I have in my config.xml

```
  <controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view>
    <observers>
      <commerceextensions_groupedproductredirect_observer>
        <class>CommerceExtensions_GroupedProductRedirect_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>redirectProductView</method>
      </commerceextensions_groupedproductredirect_observer>
    </observers>
  </controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view>
```

It will only redirect if the child product is set to Not Visible Individually and it has a parent grouped product. This can easily be adapted to work with configurable or bundle products, I just dont use those types on my own site but as long as you can get the parent product id, there is no problem.

You should be able to just add these two parts to your module and it will work perfectly. I also ended up doing one for the review pages of those child products. Its essentially the same code with some adaptations.

Comment: When using this in your site, remove this part Mage::getStoreConfig('groupedproductredirect/active/overall') as it is just from my custom module in which I set a master on/off switch for the extension.

Comment: When i added this code to the Observer file I get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/unicohom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php on line 107

Comment: you probably added an extra }. Give me a moment and I will give you an edited answer exactly as you need it.

Comment: If this answer works for you, please accept it so that I can get the credit. Thanks!

Comment: @user3315004 Did this answer work for you? If so, please mark it as accepted so that I can get credit for it. Better late than never. Thanks!